# How to Blazor compile multi file c code to wasm

Tags: blazor-webassembly

THe blazor docs show a trivial example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/webassembly-native-dependencies?view=aspnetcore-6.0 where the c code is in one file. I made my own version of that and got it to work, but now I want to compile something that has multiple files, has non trivial source tree structure, makefile etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use Emscripten (version 2.0.23) to compile all dependencies to wasm, and then link them, which is the tool that NET also uses to compile your C source.

[Emscripten](https://emscripten.org/docs/compiling/Building-Projects.html) supports make & cmake so you can change the make files to use emcc instead and rebuild the project.

Im also [asking about similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72056349/building-or-tools-for-blazor-wasm) but more library specific, perhaps the sources there can provide you with some help.

Comment: I was coming down to that conclusion - that vs only directly supported trivial c projects. Did you work out if its possible to debug the c code inside the browser - either via vs or via browser devtools

Comment: I also worked out how to do source level debugging using google bpwser plugin